# Query to retrieve values that don't exist between tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to retrieve values that doesn't exist in another table. I'm working with `Shares` and `Share_types` tables.

Currently, I have this working with PHP but I'm always looping all over the 2,500~ rows of `Share_types` and I think it is possible to solve the amount of rows with a query.

The user currently goes through this process:

1. Select the type of share - `Anual share`
2. Select the year that will be extracted - `2016`
3. Code will generate all shares until the year of `2016` that weren't yet generated. This means, that the years behind of `2016` will also be generate if they don't exist.

That said, my PHP code is like the following:

```
// Retrieves always the 2,500~ rows
$listOfShareTypes = "SELECT user_id, date_start FROM share_types WHERE type = 'Anual share'";

foreach($listOfShareTypes as $type)
{
   // Now is where I validate if the share already exists
   $hasShare = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shares WHERE the_year = $yearSelectedByUser, user_id = $type->user_id, share_type_id = $type->id";

   if($hasShare == TRUE)
      continue;
   else
      // Create the share..
}
```

So usually, to retrieve via query the results that doesn't exist in another table I would do two `select` in a query, but after a few searches it points to the use of `LEFT JOIN`. However I have no clue how to accomplish this since I need to match several fields (user_id, share_type_id, year, etc.)

Looking at this example I created on **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f58c2d/4)**, the result should be:

```
(5, 3, 'Anual', '2015-06-28')
```

And with this result and since the user selected the year of `2016` I should loop (in PHP) from `2015` until `2016`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using the wrong column in the `join` condition. The tables should be joined on `user_id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f58c2d/5)

```
SELECT stype.id, stype.user_id, stype.type, stype.date_start
FROM share_types AS stype
LEFT JOIN shares AS share ON share.user_id = stype.user_id
WHERE share.share_type_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I accepted your answer but now I faced another problem, if the user chooses '2017' it should retrieve all the rows, in this case all the 5 rows since it hasn't been added yet to the `Shares`. Do you have any clue how to do that via query?

Comment: can you add some sample data to the fiddle and show the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT user_id, date_start FROM share_types st,shares sh on sh.share_type_id=st.user_id   WHERE  type = 'Anual share' and sh.user_id=st.id and sh.the_year=$yearSelectedByUser and  Having COUNT(sh.user_id) < 1;
```